# ZipOutputStream creating corrupt (unzippable) zip file

Tags: java, sockets, networking, zipoutputstream

I am trying to send zipped bytes to another server and then have that server receive them and write out the zipped filed. When I do the zipping and writing on the same server it works great. The local version looks something like this:

```
ZipOutputStream zout = new ZipOutputStream(FileOutputStream);
zout.write(byteBuffer, 0, len);
zout.flush()
FileOutputStream.flush();
zout.close();
```

The cross server implementation creates a bad output though. The sending code is: (magic string tells the server it has received all of the data.

```
ZipOutputStream zout = new ZipOutputStream(out);
ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(fileName);
zout.putNextEntry(entry);
System.out.println("sending zipped bytes...");
zout.write(inputBuffer, contentBegin, len);
zout.flush();
zout.closeEntry();
out.flush();

byte[] magicStringData = "--------MagicStringCSE283Miami".getBytes("US-ASCII");
out.write(magicStringData, 0, magicStringData.length);
out.flush();    

System.out.println("Done writing file and sending zipped bytes.");

Thread.sleep(10000);
zout.close();
clntSock.close();  // Close the socket.  We are done with this client!
```

The receiving code looks like this:

```
        System.out.println("receiving zipped bytes...");
        byte[] inputBuffer = new byte[BUF_SIZE];
        int total2 = 0, count = 0;
        while(count != -1) { // read from origin's buffer into byteBuffer until origin is out of data
            count = inFromCompression.read(inputBuffer, total2, BUF_SIZE - total - 1);
            String msg = new String(inputBuffer, total2, count, "US-ASCII");
            total2 += count;
            if(msg.contains("-------MagicString")){
                System.out.println("full message received...");
                break;
            }
        }

        String inputString = new String(inputBuffer, 0, total2, "US-ASCII");
        int contentEnd = inputString.indexOf("--------MagicString");
        FileOutputStream fout2 = new FileOutputStream(outputFileName + ".zip");
        fout2.write(inputBuffer, 0, contentEnd);
        fout2.flush();
        fout2.close();

        System.out.println("Done writing zipped bytes.");

        //Thread.sleep(10000);
        //socketToCompression.close();
```

Any ideas? I am thinking it might be something like I am not closing the ZipOutputStream before sending the magic string that signals the end of the data, but every time I call zout.close() immediately after flushing zout it closes the entire socket.

Comment: What's the point of the magic string? Can't the socket being closed signal the end of the input? Also when you flush a stream, it flushes all underlying streams, should call closeEntry() before you flush and might need to call finish() at some point.

Comment: I'm not sure if there would have been a problem just closing the stream. Regardless, I ended up wrapping the ZipOutputStream around a ByteArrayOutputStream so I could .close() the ZipOutputStream and then I send the boas.toByteArray() over the socket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the magic string and just send and receive the actual data. You're presently throwing away any buffer that *contains* the magic string, including whatever ZIP data may have been before it.

You don't need a `ByteArrayOutputStream.`